# Is it possible to retrieve a file or folder resource by path?

Tags: box-api

Is there any way to get information about a file or folder on Box, given it's full path, but not ID?

For example, I'd like to check if `/Foo/Bar/test.txt` exists on Box. Currently, I have to start at the root and recursively walk through each folder level, searching for the next segment in the path.

As you can imagine, this process is very cumbersome when writing fully asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is not a way to retrieve files or folders by path. This is something we may consider for the future, but don't have plans to implement it in the short term.